# SQL Server unpivot table with the column headers as the tuples

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I pivot the following table. The table format given below:

[Image of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpIaa.png)

After the unpivot query i.e

```
select 
    u.parentcustomerid, u.Parentcustomer, u.Billed_Rate 
from 
    #tbl_ONOFFPVHZRate s
unpivot 
    (Billed_Rate for details in ([PV ON rate],[PV Off rate],[HZ ON rate],[HZ Off rate])) u
```

[Image of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChrTO.png)

```
parentcustomerid    Parentcustomer  Billed_Rate PV/HZ/onOFF
```

---

```
1                        ACI    346.0314334 PV on rate
1                        ACI    217.967008  PV off Rate
1                        ACI    0            HZ on Rate
1                        ACI    187.1165653 HZ off Rate
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a Cross Apply

```
Declare @YourTable table (parentCustomerid int,parentcustomer varchar(50),[PV On rate] decimal(18,13),[PV Off rate] decimal(18,13),[Hz On Rate] decimal(18,13),[Hz Off Rate] decimal(18,13))
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,'ACI',346.031433420653,217.967008048837,0,187.116565263531),
(2,'ADP',639.236987707151, 44.174136118757,379.378754724713,76.539884754392)

Select parentCustomerid
      ,parentcustomer
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ([PV On rate] ,'PV On rate')
                     ,([PV Off rate],'PV Off rate')
                     ,([Hz On Rate] ,'Hz On Rate')
                     ,([Hz Off Rate] ,'Hz Off Rate')
             ) B ([Billed_Rate],[PV/HZ/onOFF])
```

Returns

```
parentCustomerid    parentcustomer  Billed_Rate         PV/HZ/onOFF
1                   ACI             346.0314334206530   PV On rate
1                   ACI             217.9670080488370   PV Off rate
1                   ACI             0.0000000000000     Hz On Rate
1                   ACI             187.1165652635310   Hz Off Rate
2                   ADP             639.2369877071510   PV On rate
2                   ADP             44.1741361187570    PV Off rate
2                   ADP             379.3787547247130   Hz On Rate
2                   ADP             76.5398847543920    Hz Off Rate
```